# iptables - как перенаправить пакет на другой ip не меняя адреса получателя?

Tags: iptables

Есть компьютер пользователя, сервер и роутер. Компьютер пользователя и сервер подключены к роутеру и находятся в одной локальной сети. На сервере установлен proxy и [redsocks](http://darkk.net.ru/redsocks/). Redsocks - это соксификатор, он принимает обычные http соединения и отправляет их на socks5 прокси.

**Задача**: нужно сделать так, чтобы при попытке зайти с компьютера пользователя на определённый сайт, запрос не уходил напрямую в интернет, а проходил через прокси на сервере.
Давайте для простоты примем что все запросы пользователя должны проходить через прокси на сервере.

Чтобы было понятней, я нарисовал [image: диаграмму].

**Часть решения**: на сервере уже работает прокси и redsocks. Запросы на самом сервере локально получается перенаправлять на порт redsocks, откуда они через прокси идут в интернет.

**Проблема**: Как мне на роутере перенаправить на сервер запросы, которые идут от компьютера пользователя в интернет?
Везде пишут про DNAT, но такое правило не помогает. Так как адрес получателя меняется на адрес сервера. И соксификатор, получая такой пакет, видит что он предназначается ему, а не какому-то ресурсу в интернете. А значит через прокси его не направляет.
А вот правило REDIRECT работает, но оно направляет пакет только на другой порт, но не на другой ip. То есть, если бы я мог установить redsocks на роутер, то всё заработало бы. Но на роутере у меня нет места для установки доп. пакетов.

Я думал написать правило, которое бы перенаправляло на конкретный интерфейс, а не на ip, но не смог найти этот отдельный интерфейс в роутере. Такое впечатление, что и сервер и компьютер подключены к одному интерфейсу lan. (Роутер с прошивкой OpenWRT).
Но в интерфейсах я вообще мало что понимаю.

Comment: в описанной ситуации наиболее логично, с моей точки зрения, указать на компьютере шлюзом по умолчанию — сервер.

Answer (score 1):

в описанной ситуации наиболее логично и продуктивно, с моей точки зрения, указать на компьютере шлюзом по умолчанию — сервер.

если компьютер получает настройки сети по *dhcp* — достаточно изменить настройки у *dhcp*-сервера касательно информации, выдаваемой данному компьютеру.

если сетевая система компьютера настроена статически и изменить её нет возможности — поменяйте ip-адреса между маршрутизатором и сервером.

---

более сложное и затратное решение — воспользоваться программой [*ebtables*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ebtables). это примерно то же самое, что и *iptables*, тоже управляет подсистемой [*netfilter*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netfilter) программы *linux*, но касается движения пакетов на следующем (в глубину) уровне сетевого стека.

пример использования *ebtables* в *openwrt*: https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/netfilter/netfilter.ebtables.example1

Comment: Интересное решение. Про dhcp - возьму как запасной вариант. Всё же хотелось, чтобы доступ в интернет не зависел от работоспособности сервера. Про ebtables - неплохо, но смущает в описании заметка, что наблюдается существенное снижение скорости.

Comment: и без «описаний заметок», мне кажется, вполне очевидно, что в таком варианте будет существенное снижение скорости: из трёх упомянутых компьютеров самый слабый процессор и самый маленький объём оп. памяти —  у маршрутизатора, и как раз на него ложится двойная нагрузка — каждый пакет должен обрабатываться дважды. и программа ebtables (да и вообще netfilter) здесь вообще ни при чём: такова желаемая вами топология хождения пакетов.

Comment: не знаю, что именно в прочитанном вами говорится про снижение скорости, но, конечно, понятно, что время пересылки ethenet-фрейма значительно меньше времени, занимаего процессом: 1. пересылки того же фрейма одному адаптеру. 2. передачи его из адаптера в процессор. 3. обработки процессором. 4. передачи назад адаптеру. 5. пересылки другому адаптеру.